# Which among the following is true for a differentiable function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Let $f$ be a non negative function and has a finite third derivative in the open interval $(0,1)$, then $f'''(c) = 0$ for some $c \in (0,1)$ if :

(a) $f(x) =0$ for atleast two values of $x \in (0,1)$

(b) $f(x) = 0$ for atleast one value of $x \in (0,1)$

(c) $f'(x) = 0$ for atleast two values of $x \in (0,1)$

(d) None of these

Using a counterexample $f(x) = (x - 1/2)^4$ we can  say options (a) and (c) are clearly false, But I am not able

to prove/disprove option (b)

Any hints ??

Comment: Choose $f(x)=1$ for example to disprove b)

Comment: I don't understand how any of these are counterexamples. $(x-1/2)^4$ is not equal to $0$ for two values of $x$, nor is $\frac{d}{dx}(x-1/2)^4$ equal to $0$ for two values of $x$. So they don't even meet the conditions (a) and (c) require, how can they be counterexamples?

Comment: Same with $f(x)=1$, it is not equal to $0$ for any $x$, so how can it be a counterexample to (b)?

Comment: A counterexample to (b) would be a function $f(x)$ which is equal to 0 for some $x\in(0, 1)$ and such that $f'''(c)\neq0$ for all $c\in(0, 1)$... right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) is true: If $0<a<b<1$ and $f(a)=0=f(b),$ then $f$ has minimums at $a,b.$ This implies $f'(a)=f'(b)=0.$ But note also $f$ has a local maximum at some $c\in (a,b),$ where $f'(c)=0.$ Thus $f'=0$ at three distinct points. The MVT then implies $f''$ at two distinct points. Apply MVT again to see $f'''=0$ somewhere.

(b) is false: Let $f(x)=(x-1/2)^2+(x-1/2)^3.$ Then $f(1/2)=0,$ $f>0$ on $(0,1),$ and $f'''\equiv 6.$

Hint for (c): Let $0<a<b<1.$ Think of $f'(x)=(x-a)(x-b).$

Answer (score 0):

To complete zhw's answer:

Counterexample to (c): $$f(x)=\left(9x-2\right)^{2}+\left(9x-2\right)^{3}$$

Note that $f'(x)=2(9x-2)(9)+3(9x-2)^2(9)$ which has roots at $x=2/9$ and $x=4/27$. However, $f'''(x)=4374$.

The counterexamples you gave don't work because they are counterexamples for the converse statements, not the originals.

Comment: Thank you! for spotting my mistake.